# Encrypt all user data in my web application

Tags: security, encryption, hash, redis

This is not a typical StackOverflow question as it is quite specific and bound to my current project. Given my project ([GitHub link](https://github.com/ihucos/counter.dev)), I would like to encrypt or handle all user data in a way that impedes me as a service provider to view data of specific users. This would probably not be feasible in a typical webapp with a rational SQL database. I am using Redis with data that is basically structured as follows:

Users can view their data filtered by two dimensions: A time range and a domain. These are further grouped by another dimension, which are multiple charts. So there is data for countries, top landing pages, etc (It's a web analytics app). Internally of course I also need to have the user baked in as dimension in the key that holds data for a chart and of course there is some indexing stuff going on.

Now here is the idea: I could hash the access key for this single charts - I am only doing direct key access anyway and no scanning (filtering over keys). Furthermore I would only save the hashed username in the database so the username becomes the missing information I don't have to retrieve the payloads.

This would leave me with the cleartext payloads, which represent specific charts given by specific user selections (Yes, I only save the user data in an aggregated form btw) but I would have no reasonable way to map a single chart to a specific user or domain. Given I have ~70 integrated users at the moment, it would be not feasible to try to manually map data points to specific users (But I could still see all domains a "user" uses).

Of course this is relying on the username being somewhat a secret and I would only save the hashed username to the database and only handle the cleartext username in ram. I can still greet the user since the cleartext username is saved in a cookie :-)

With usernames being too short and having almost no entropy of course I could brute force my own database in order to regain the missing links and access to all data individual users have. But before doing this the more obvious way to "cheat" would be to just run another software (without that hashing) on the server but still stating everything is encrypted. So my point is that the presented solution is good enough for a hosted service.

Does this sound plausible? Would such an approach add an additional layer of security or be meaningless because it is too easy to circumvent?

In my opinion I could compare this with locking a bicycle with a very cheap lock. Even if the lock is easily breakable it does have a strong symbolic meaning that someone that breaks the lock is doing something worse than stealing a bicycle that has no lock at all. So even it is not possible to protect user data from a hosting provider, it is possible to make the work to do so more "dirty" and such socially and legally less acceptable. Does this makes sense? :-)

So my question is: security by obscurity or sound approach?

Cheers!